# I just put one entry point but a lot of files compile in webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I have only one entry point, but when compile files with webpack-dev-server, it compiles a lot of files.

My webpack.config:

```
const path = require('path');
module.exports = {
  entry: path.resolve(__dirname+'../../../../modules/beshop_mainmenu/views/js/back.js'),
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, '../../../../modules/beshop_mainmenu/views/js/'),
    publicPath: "back/",
    filename:'back.js'
  },
  mode:'development',
  module:{
    rules:[{
      test: /\.css$/,
      use:['style-loader','css-loader'],
    },]
  }
}
```

The result:
[image: result]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It compiles a lot of files because the entry file for `webpack-dev-server/client` includes all those files (url, strip-ansi, etc). Webpack builds everything from your entry point. So it is normal, nothing is unusual.